# Install drywall on narrow corner adjacent to closet door frame

Tags: drywall

I'm looking to finish the inside wall of my closet by putting up drywall. Most of the closet is finished, but the backside of the wall with the sliding door on it isn't.

There's a vertical wood stud that sticks out ½ inch past the door frame, and I'm not sure I can reasonably fit drywall onto that narrow surface.

Photo from the inside, looking up and towards the room (the phone cord is unimportant and will be removed):

[image: Photo of wall looking out]

I sketched the area for my own reference:

[image: Sketch: Front and side views]
[image: Sketch: Top view]

How can I finish this? I thought I might install drywall onto the larger surface, then wrap corner bead around the new drywall and directly onto the wood stud. Is this reasonable? Is there a better option?

Comment: that electric cable is going to get in the way too, you probably need drill though the overhang of the lintel and run it inside the wall.

Comment: Just curious - how did you manage to buy a door that wasn't made for a standard interior door opening - 3-1/2 for 2x4 frame plus 1" (total) for drywall on either side?

Comment: It was like this when I got here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add the wallboard to the larger portion of the wall to the opening of the door, stopping all drywall at the door opening, the short portion you have the measuring tape on could take a jamb extension. Which is a piece of wood or MDF cut to fit the space out to the new face of the drywall and that will be trimmed with the same door casing as the outside.

If you are not concerned about going into that much detail, then after the wallboard is set on the larger wall, cover the corner with a nail on corner bead and smooth over with mud, sand and paint. No need to trifle with that small of a piece of drywall. the corner bead will cover it all. If you wish after that, you could add a small piece of molding like quarter round at the inside corner of the corner bead and door jamb to help finish it out a little better.

Comment: +1 on the jamb extension.  That's a fairly standard part of putting new windows into existing openings, for instance.